# Unable to call angular service the second time

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

I am trying to call a service function on click of a button in angular. I dono if i am doing it the right way. The first time i am able to call the service and retreive the values the second time when i click the button it throws the following error.
[This is the error]

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: this._posterService.getPosterUrl is not a function
    at HomeComponent.downloadFile (home.component.ts:63)
    at HomeComponent_div_31_Template_a_click_9_listener (home.component.html:56)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14316)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14351)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
```

This is my code.

```html
 <a (click)="downloadFile(product._id)" class="genric-btn primary" style="color: aliceblue;">Download</a>
```

```
downloadFile(value:any):void{
    this.subs = this._posterService.getPosterUrl(value).subscribe(res => {
      this._posterService = res;
      console.log(res)
       this.DownloadUrl = "assets/img/test.pdf"
       let link = document.createElement("a");
       link.download = "filename";
       link.href = this.DownloadUrl;
       link.click(); 
       });
    }
```

Here i am subscribing to the service. when i click the button i an invoking the finction and the ID is passed to the function.

```
public getPosterUrl=(posterId:string):Observable<any> =>{
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posters/'+posterId);
  }
```

I am able to get the first request made to the service. When i try to click the button the second time. The error is thrown.

Comment: **core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: this._posterService.getPosterUrl is not a function** This is the error Sorry i guess the image did not get uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this:

```
this._posterService = res;
```

you are losing your service instance which was injected by angular. Therefore you can only run the service function for one time, just remove that line or try to explain what were you trying achieve with it for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax, there should be no = sign after public getPosterUrl
It should be

```
public getPosterUrl(posterId:string):Observable<any> => {    
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posters/'+posterId);    
}
```